# Can ApplicationInsights track events across many WebApps/LogicApps/etc?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-application-insights

I have the following resources

- One Mobile/API app
- One MVC app
- Three Logic apps
- One Azure function deployment with 5 functions

I want to have a single tracking number (correlation ID) to track across all instances at the same time.  I'm looking at the Contoso Insurance sample, but I'm rebuilding it by hand (not using Azure Deploy scripts).

I've read the deployment code, but I'm not sure if I can merge app insight logs together, or if it's a hack of some sort.

**Observations**

When I right click on visual studio, I can only associate to Application insights instances that aren't already connected to a *app (web | mobile | api).

However, in the configuration, I can give Application insights a direct GUID which might allow me to achieve the goal of one App Insights activity log for the entire process

**Question**

1. Is it possible to have one app insights log among all Mobile/API/Logic/MVC sites?
2. Is there a way to have (or should I have) one standard app insights instance per web app, then a special dedicated shared app insights instance for my code to call into and log?
3. What is contoso insurance doing with Azure App Insights?

Answer (score 5):

Jeff from Logic Apps team here -- So the answer is yes - but there are some caveats.  We are working to make the experience seamless and automatic, but for now it will require the following.  First as a heads up:

First, for Logic Apps we have what's called the [client tracking ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps#client-tracking-id) -- this is a header you can set on an incoming HTTP Request or Service Bus message to track and correlate events across actions.  It will be sent to all steps (functions, connectors, etc.) with the `x-ms-client-tracking-id` header.

Logic Apps emits all logs to [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview) - which unfortunately today only has  a sink into Event Hubs, Storage, and Log Analytics -- not App Insights.

With all of that in-mind, here's the architecture we see many following:

1. Have your web apps just emit to App Insights directly.  Use some correlation ID as needed.  When firing any Logic Apps, pass in the `x-ms-client-tracking-id` header so you can correlate events.
2. Log your events to App Insights in the Function app.  This [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/tmurphy/archive/2017/02/16/logging-to-application-insights-in-azure-functions.aspx) details some of how to do that, and it is [also being worked on](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/727) for a better experience soon.
3. In your logic app - either write a Function to consume events off of Azure monitor and push to App Insights, or write a function that is an App Insight "logger" that you can call in your workflow to also get the data into App Insights.

This is how Contoso Insurance is leveraging App Insights as far as I understand.  We are working across all teams (App Insights, Azure Monitor, Azure Functions, Logic Apps) to make this super-simple and integrated in the coming weeks/months, but for now achievable with above.  Feel free to reach out for any ?s

Comment: Oh, so all the events are being relayed via that endpoint.  I can hold off for a few months for a more supported approach. Will keep an eye out.